# Finding if something is within a range programmatically

Tags: algorithm, math

I know this is a simple math problem but for some reason im drawing a blank.

If I have two ints which are boundaries for a range:

```
int q = 100;
int w = 230;
```

and then another in that is a number that I want to see if it is inside of the range:

```
int e = ?;
```

How can I find if `e` is in the bounds of `q` and `w`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are we talking C here?

```
(e >= q) && (e <= w)
```

Comment: Haha that could work, I guess I was thinking to hard.  I was trying some crazy things...

Comment: After looking at the other answers, you probably should make clear your assumptions about q and w.  Which one is smaller / larger etc.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to find which of `q` and `w` is your lower bound and which is your upper bound.

```
int upper, lower;

if (q <= w) {
    lower = q;
    upper = w;
} else {
    lower = w; 
    upper = q;
}
```

Then you just perform a simple test

```
if (lower <= e) && (e <= upper) {
     // e is within the range
} else {
     // e is outside the range
}
```

This assumes that you want the range to include `q` and `w`. Otherwise, replace `<=` with `<`.

Answer (score 0):

For some obfuscation:

```
#define IN_RANGE(q,w,e) (((q > w ? q : w) > e) && ((q < w ? q : w) < e)) ? 1 : 0
```

Before you start talking about how terrible defines are, this is just a "simple" example.